# Как получить позицию определенной вкладки QTabBar?

Tags: c++, qt

Необходимо получить `QRect` определенной вкладки в `QTabBar`, то есть её координаты и ширину с высотой. Метод `tabRect();`, к сожалению, возвращает лишь прямоугольник с шириной и высотой, но с координатами 0, 0. Как можно получить глобальные координаты вкладки по определенному индексу? Так же, как работает `tabRect()`, только чтобы там были ещё и координаты.
P.S. под вкладкой подразумевается только панелька на панели вкладок(не `QTabWidget`).

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `mapToGlobal`/`mapToParent` методы `QWidget`

Comment: @ixSci Ну так `mapToGlobal` принимает параметр `QPoint`, я спрашиваю, откуда взять эти координаты.

Comment: Т.е. передать туда (0,0) Вы не догадались?

Comment: @ixSci, `newRect = mapToParent(rect.topLeft())` или даже `rect.translate(mapToParent(rect.topLeft()))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Qt нет жёстко зашитого возврата нулевых координат верхнего левого угла вкладки. В этом можно убедиться, заглянув в исходные коды этого фреймворка.

***[/src/gui/widgets/qtabbar.cpp](https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/0a2f2382541424726168804be2c90b91381608c6/src/gui/widgets/qtabbar.cpp)*** (приведены фрагменты, отвечающие за формирование координат вкладок):

```
QRect QTabBar::tabRect(int index) const
{
    Q_D(const QTabBar);
    if (const QTabBarPrivate::Tab *tab = d->at(index)) {
        if (d->layoutDirty)
            const_cast<QTabBarPrivate*>(d)->layoutTabs();
        QRect r = tab->rect;
        if (verticalTabs(d->shape))
            r.translate(0, -d->scrollOffset);
        else
            r.translate(-d->scrollOffset, 0);
        if (!verticalTabs(d->shape))
            r = QStyle::visualRect(layoutDirection(), rect(), r);
        return r;
    }
    return QRect();
}

// ....

QTabBarPrivate::Tab *QTabBarPrivate::at(int index)
{
    return validIndex(index)?&tabList[index]:0;
}

// ...

void QTabBarPrivate::layoutTabs()
{
    // ...

    for (i = 0; i < tabList.count(); ++i) {
        const QLayoutStruct &lstruct = tabChain.at(i + 1);
        if (!vertTabs)
            tabList[i].rect.setRect(lstruct.pos, 0, lstruct.size, maxExtent);
        else
            tabList[i].rect.setRect(0, lstruct.pos, maxExtent, lstruct.size);
    }

    // ...
}
```

То есть у горизонтальных вкладок нулевой является исключительно координата *Y*. Вторая координата возрастает линейно и зависит от номера вкладки, ширины предшествующих вкладок и сдвига всей панели (можно задавать стрелками в случае, когда строка вкладок не помещается на экран).

Другое дело, что координаты хранятся относительно `QTabBar`, а потому необходимо перевести координаты в пространство нужного виджета:

```
QRect tabRect = myTabBar->tabRect(tabId);
tabRect.translate(mapTo(targetWidget, tabRect.topLeft));
```

Comment: Всё понятно, спасибо. Теперь работает. А что это за такое объявление экзотическое `QTabBarPrivate::Tab *QTabBarPrivate::at`, что оно означает?

Comment: Метод `at` класса `QTabBarPrivate`, возвращающий указатель на `QTabBarPrivate::Tab`. В языке C++ неважно, к чему «прилеплена» звёздочка указателя, важен лишь её относительный порядок среди «слов» исходного кода.